# Текст лесенкой js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такой вывод текста на js?
Без наклона
[image: пример]

```css
.reviews__item{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 390px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #ffd92f;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.reviews__text{
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  transform: skew(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class=" reviews__item">
  <p class="reviews__text">
  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст  текст 
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Здесь без js может кому пригодится

```css
.skew {    
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 235px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%, #64D094 50%);
    shape-outside: polygon(12% 100% , 100% 0%, 0 0%);
}
.txt {
  word-break: break-word;
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: justify;
}
.skew2 {    
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 15%;
    height: 235px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, #64D094 50%);
    shape-outside: polygon(0% 100% , 100% 0%, 90% 0%);
}
#container{
  height: 235px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="skew"></div>
  <div class="skew2"></div>
  <div class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. У меня была такая идея на крайний случай, думал есть оптимальное решение на js. В общем воспользуюсь вашим решением, спасибо ещё раз)

Comment: На здоровье! :)

Answer (score 3):

Можно вычислить исходя из угла наклона и высоты строки необходимый отступ для каждой строки (`line`). По идее затем надо разбить текст на строки по какому-то алгоритму, поместить их в `span` и каждому span задать отдельный `margin`.

Не знаком с алгоритмами разбиения текста на отдельные строки, тем более надо учитывать будет последующие отступы. Поэтому разбил текст сразу на отдельные строки с помощью `<span></span><br>`.

Опять же, если `line-height` не определена явно, то `getComputedStyle` возвращает `'normal'`. Методом подбора, на глаз, определил, что это значит `1.2`, но могу ошибаться.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.skewed');
const text = div.querySelector('.text');
const spans = text.querySelectorAll('span');

const font_size = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(text).fontSize);
const skew_angle = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(div).transform.split(',')[2]);
let line_height = window.getComputedStyle(text).lineHeight;
line_height = line_height === 'normal' ? font_size * 1.2 : parseFloat(line_height);

const line_margin = line_height * Math.sin(skew_angle);

let cur_margin = 0;
spans.forEach(span => {
    span.style.marginLeft = cur_margin + 'px';
    cur_margin += line_margin;
})
```

```css
.skewed{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 390px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #ffd92f;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.skewed .text {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  transform: skew(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed">
  <p class="text">
    <span>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</span><br>
    <span>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</span><br>
    <span>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</span><br>
    <span>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</span><br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Решение конечно хорошее, но, увы в моем случае не подойдёт тк в дальнейшем текст будет добавляться с админки и там обертку сделать не лучшее решение

Comment: На здоровье! :-) Можно динамическое построчное разбиение на span сделать и привязать к window.onresize даже, но, конечно, лучше элементарное автоматическое решение через css))