# Подскажите как можно реализовать такой вывод текста?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как можно реализовать такой вывод текста по всему сайту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего, имелось ввиду непрямоугольная форма блока с тектом. Вот хорошая статья на эту тему: [Создание непрямоугольных макетов при помощи CSS-форм](https://frontender.info/css-shapes/).

Comment: Может натолкнет на [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355070/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-js/1355094#1355094)

Comment: Вот ещё немного ссылок на тему: [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside), [3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes/Overview_of_CSS_Shapes), [4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes/Basic_Shapes).